# How to use stat with geom_violin in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been messing around with geom_violin from ggplot2.  I'm able to generate an ugly plot shown below.

[image]

I think if I apply a log transformation or something to the data, it will be more clear.

In the geom_violin [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_violin.html), I noticed that there is a parameter called stat. By default, it is set to ydensity. Looking at the [source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/6586743/) , its not clear to me what transformations I can pass into this function. Does anyone know where I can find more documentation for this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ggplot2`, the `stat` is a function applied to the data. `stat="identity"` leaves the data as is (say, for plotting points). `stat="bin"` bins the data for plotting a histogram. `stat="smooth"` creates a regression smoother from the data. In this case, `stat="ydensity"` just means that `geom_violin` by default calculates the kernel density for creating the violin plot.

If you want a violin plot of the log of the data, you could just pass log(data) to `geom_violin` instead of the data itself.

Also, take a look at [the help for `stat_summary`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html), which allows you to apply your own functions to the data and then select the `geom` you want to use to plot it.

Comment: I think that stat_summary function was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Have a look to the     scale argument in     geom_violin . Using scale="width" (all violins have the same maximum width) might imrpove readability of your plot